# Tikz Fractals - How can I create this snowflake pattern?

Tags: tikz-pgf, fractals

I am playing around with `tikz` and am trying to reproduce the figure below:
[image: original picture]

My code so far is as below,

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.fractals}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\footnotesize, decoration=Koch curve type 1]
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Shape 1
    \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (B) at (3,0);
    \coordinate (C) at (3,3);
    \coordinate (D) at (0,3);
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \draw (A) rectangle (C);
    \node at (1.5,1.5) {$S_1$};
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Shape 2
    \begin{scope}[xshift=5cm]
    \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (B) at (3,0);
    \coordinate (C) at (3,3);
    \coordinate (D) at (0,3);
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \draw decorate{ (D) -- (C) -- (B) -- (A) -- cycle};
    \node at (1.5,1.5) {$S_2$};
    \end{scope}
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Shape 3
    \begin{scope}[xshift=11cm]
    \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (B) at (3,0);
    \coordinate (C) at (3,3);
    \coordinate (D) at (0,3);
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \draw decorate{ decorate{ (D) -- (C) -- (B) -- (A) -- cycle} };
    \node at (1.5,1.5) {$S_3$};
    \end{scope}
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

producing the output:
[image: my output]

I can not get the third picture right.

The rule: Subsequent terms are obtained by replacing the *middle* third of each external edge of a new square formed in the previous snowfake, by a square 1/3 of the size.

Obviously I have to fiddle with the Koch curve definition but my knowledge of the library is very limited to do so. Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: This seems to be the expected behaviour of `Koch curve type 1` fractals

Comment: Did you check section 55 Lindenmayer system drawing library of the pgfmanual version 3.0.1a ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe not the most elegant answer, but it could be useful.

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.fractals}

% Creates a "_|-|_" looking shape defined by the start position, the start angle and the length of every segment of the path
\newcommand{\decoratededge}[3]{
\draw #1 -- ++ (90+#2:#3) decorate{--++ (180+#2:#3) --++ (90+#2:#3) --++ (0+#2:#3)} --++ (90+#2:#3);
}

\begin{document}
    % Draws the manually defined 5 segment path
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \decoratededge{(0,0)}{0}{1/3}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    % Draws the manually defined 5 segment path with a decoration of the 3 middle segments
    \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\footnotesize, decoration=Koch curve type 1]
        \decoratededge{(0,0)}{0}{1/3}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    % Draws the complete figure
    \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\footnotesize, decoration=Koch curve type 1]
        \decoratededge{(0,0)}{0}{1/3}
        \decoratededge{(0,1)}{-90}{1/3}
        \decoratededge{(1,1)}{-180}{1/3}
        \decoratededge{(1,0)}{-270}{1/3}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, your approach does indeed what I had in mind.

Comment: I had a look at the lindenmayer library, but It is not that simple to use at first sight. I hope it helps